# downloading ubuntu (18.04.1) in my dell laptop

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, dell, windows-10, performance

I wanted to know that if my dell laptop will run smoothly in ubuntu linux os(18.04.1) or not.My laptop name is "DELL INSPIRON 15 3542".I have installed win 10 pro in my laptop and now wants to install linux os.If it not run well then suggest me that which another os i install in my laptop.I will give you all information regarding my laptop.I will be waiting for your response.

[about my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhYWq.png)

Intel(R)Core(TM)i3-4005U cpu @1.70GHz

4.00GB Ram

64-bit os,x64-based processor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

To test this, there is a function to "Try Ubuntu live" at the installer. It will run Ubuntu without actually installing it.

*(At least there was when I last checked)*

Answer (score 0):

*As per your configuration, try to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit, which runs smoothly.*

Answer (score 0):

I am running 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15. Mine has an 8 core I5, 8 gig RAM and a 1TB harddisk but other than that the platform is much the same as yours.

Hibernation doesn't work. I might be able to sort that out sometime but I haven't had the time to look into it. My previous laptop was a none-core HP500 with 12.04 on it, and hibernation didn't work there, either, so that's not specific to the Dell Inspiron series.

Suspend ("sleep mode") work fine, but sometimes (albeit very rarely) my root fs is mounted read-only after resume, and sometimes (just as seldom) my sound device had disappeared after resume and I need to do a "pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload" to get it back.

Note that I have no idea if these issues are Ubuntu-related or hardware related. I installed 18.04 two days after it was released because that's when my previous laptop broke and I decided to take the leap rather than mess around with 17.04 at that time. :)

Other than the above trivialities, I have no issues whatsoever. Everything works and works smoothly. Wifi, Bluetooth, wired Ethernet, video, USB, sound, you name it; it's all working fine. I have  moved my Win10 install to a VirtualBox environment on top of Ubuntu so that I can still run Win apps if I absolutely must, but I only start it when I have to because my laptop's battery life is longer when running Ubuntu 18.04 than it was with Win10.

So my advise would be to go for it! You should have no major issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fully test your system, if everything works fine.
[How To by Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0)

If the system is running not smooth, you can try a [Flavours](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours), like **Lubuntu**.
Lubuntu doesn't need much resources.